# Material Design Bottom Button in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android

Look at the following example Layout from Gmail:

[image]

There is a button at the bottom of the listview with a pen as icon.

How can I create such a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is called "FloatingActionButton", search it on GitHub you will get lots of library, for example:

- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton
- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple you just need to use ImageButton